# Iron-Router infinite loop onBeforeAction

Tags: meteor, iron-router

since Meteor 1.0, I have an infinite loop in the hook onBeforeAction. (create_game is called forever)

```
onBeforeAction: function(){

if(Meteor.userId()){

  Meteor.call('create_game', this.params._id, 1, function(error, result){
    if (error)
    console.log(error);
    else{
     game_sus = result; 
     Session.set('gamesolo_id', game_sus); 
   }
  });
}
this.next();  

},

waitOn: function() { return Meteor.subscribe('game', Session.get('gamesolo_id))}
```

The infinite loop is due to the session variable cause if I remove it, I do not enter in a loop. I don't know if it's a bug due to the new version or what, but do you have any idea how could I fix this?
I tried with a global variable instead of a session variable, but I do not subscribe with that way.

Answer (score 2):

onBeforeAction is reactive so if You set the Session variable in Meteor.call callback then onBeforeAction will run again

you can use onRun for this Session setup